Where does RubyMine find ruby versions?
Where does RubyMine find the versions of ruby to use on MacOS (Arm64 chip)?
I use rbenv for version management. The ONLY version of ruby I have installed on my machine right now is 3.3.1.

However, RubyMine seems to think I have 2.7.2 installed as well. This is incorrect - the path that it is displaying in this screenshot does NOT exist. I have no clue where it is finding this.

Even more frustrating, EVERY SINGLE TIME I close and reopen RubyMine, the selected ruby version gets reset to the (non-existent) 2.7.2 and I get hit with this error that 2.7.2 doesn't exist (obviously):

Where is it getting this incorrect information?
(BTW I have asked this on the IntelliJ forums but those do not see nearly as much traffic).

You've got 2.7.2 selected and set as the default in RubyMine's Settings, as your screenshot shows.

Also make sure that $HOME/.rbenv/shims is in your $PATH for RubyMine.

Thanks @matt. If I had taken the screenshot with 3.3.1 expanded you would have seen “Default” selected there as well. TBH I’m not sure what “Default” actually indicates here because in previous (working) iterations it will be selected for every single Ruby version. And my PATH is setup correctly I did double check that already.

That looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-32918/Uninstalled-rbenv-ruby-version-still-shows-up-in-SDK-list Please check whether it helps if you close all the projects inside RubyMine (there will be a Welcome screen) and after that re-open them back.

@Olivia - I had tried closing the app, restarting the computer, and every combination. TBH there were other things acting strangely (this was a branch new machine I was setting up), so I just found it easier to wipe and start over. Now everything is working fine.

fyi - Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@DavidMakogon Specific cases for using images Images are appropriate when the information cannot be conveyed by copying and pasting text. For example: **When the text appears in a GUI, and can't be selected or copied out of that GUI. **

Everything you provided, aside from the left-side bar in the 2nd image, can be posted as text. Please see the link I provided which explains many reasons why images of text should not be used.
